# Know when a Cloud Function is complete

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

I have a Firebase Cloud Function which generates thumbnails off an image uploaded. I would like to let the client know that the Cloud Function is complete so the thumbnails can be downloaded. Is that possible, if so, how?

Comment: Just thinking out loud but you can store the status of thumbnail generation in firebase database somewhere and read it from there whether thumbnail is available or not. For example thumbnailStatus->[ImageID]->true

Comment: That is a good idea. I’m assuming I can write to the DB from Firebase Functions right?

Comment: Absolutely you can do that. If you need any help in that just update the question and will help you out.

Comment: I will look into their documentation on how to do that.